# wordpress nginx ssl redirect loop

Tags: wordpress, ssl, nginx

So I'm setting up an nginx server and installed wordpress and SSL.

The site is working perfectly on both http and https but when I try to redirect http to https via nginx's server block, both http and https results in a endless redirect loop.

Here's my server block

```
server {
    listen 80;
    return         301 $server_name$request_uri;
    listen 443 ssl spdy;
    root /var/www/wordpress;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name www.example.com;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:20m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    spdy_headers_comp 6;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/www.example.com.certchain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/www.example.com.key;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";
    add_header        Alternate-Protocol  443:npn-spdy/2;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

    access_log   /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log;
    error_log    /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log;

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }


location / {
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    if ($http_referer ~* (buttons-for-website.com)) { return 444; }
    if ($http_referer ~* (semalt.com)) { return 444; }
    }


    location ~ \.(hh|php)$ {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
        fastcgi_keep_conn on;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
        fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;
    fastcgi_cache microcache;
    fastcgi_cache_valid 200 60m;

 }

  location ~ \.php$ {

  location @fallback {
try_files $uri =404;
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;
```

fastcgi_cache microcache;
   fastcgi_cache_valid 200 60m;

```
 }


 # Cache Static Files For As Long As Possible
location ~*
 \.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|css|rss|atom|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|$
{
  access_log off;
  log_not_found off;
  expires max;
   }
# Security Settings For Better Privacy Deny Hidden Files
location ~ /\. {
deny all;
access_log off;
log_not_found off;
}
# Return 403 Forbidden For readme.(txt|html) or license.(txt|html)
if ($request_uri ~* "^.+(readme|license)\.(txt|html)$") {
 return 403;
}
# Disallow PHP In Upload Folder
location /wp-content/uploads/ {
location ~ \.php$ {
deny all;
}
}
}
```

I'd really appreciate anyone's help. I commented out that "return 301" in 3rd line and google indexed both http and https version of the same page and deindexed most of my pages and dropped rankings for several keywords.

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try separating the non ssl server block so you'd have this

```
server {
    listen 80;
    return         301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl spdy;
    root /var/www/wordpress;
....
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment Brian. Yeah it's properly redirecting now. When I try to access the site at http://www.example.com and http://example.com,  it's perfectly redirecting to https://www.example.com but when I enter https://example.com, it's not redirecting to https://www.example.com but loads the page in  https://example.com itself.

Comment: Here's how my current code looks like :

'server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl spdy;
        root /var/www/wordpress;
        server_name www.example.com;

        index index.php index.html index.htm;
....
}'

Comment: For the www. redirect you'll need to add one more server block for it
server {
    listen 443 ssl spdy;
    server name_example.com;

    return 301 https://www.$host$requesturi;
} and add a server_name www.example.com; directive to your other 443 server block or add default_server to the listen options in that sever block.